# C reading a file of binary numbers drops first char

Tags: arrays, c

Can anyone help me understand why the first char read from the file is dropped when I increase the file size to be > 19 rows?

When I run this with < 20 rows it works perfect, reads the input and dumps it.  when I add a 20th row the first row of input drops the leading char when I print the array.

Im lost. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {

  int i, j = 0;
  FILE *pFile;
  char string[20][12];
  char file_contents_resultset[20][12];
  

  pFile = fopen("sonar.txt", "r");
  if (pFile == NULL)
    {
      printf ("error opening file");
      return 0;
    }
  // Load 20 row of input into in an array and store a copy
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
      fscanf (pFile, "%12s", &string[i]);
      strcpy (file_contents_resultset[i], string[i]);
    }

  //Dump the first 5 rows of the array
  printf ("Dump array contents \n");
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {
          printf ("%c", file_contents_resultset[i][j]);
        }
      printf ("\n");
    }

  fclose (pFile);

  return 0;
};
```

This is my input file.

```
000110010001
101000110000
000110010111
100011100010
111001100001
001010001010
010100100101
011000010000
111111011010
001111011101
011011010010
001100010101
001010101100
000000000000
100010111111
100100110011
111100100001
011110001110
000110100101
011101111001
```

and this is the output

```
Dump array contents 
00110010001
101000110000
000110010111
100011100010
111001100001
```

and this is the output if I delete the 20th row of input in the input file.  Note the first char is no longer dropped.

```
Dump array contents 
000110010001
101000110000
000110010111
100011100010
111001100001
```

Comment: Given this declaration: `char string[20][12];`, you should be calling `fscanf (pFile, "%11s", string[i]);` (note 11 = 12 - 1).  If in fact you want 12 characters, you should be declaring `char string[20][13]`.  You always have to remember to add allow one more character for the null terminator.  Also note that you generally don't need the `&` when reading strings with `%s`.

Comment: true - I guess I was trying to strip off the line returns and deal only wiht the data.  when I increase it to 13 things seem to work well.   any idea why it only seemed to fail for me when the number of rows of input exceeded 19?

Comment: Probably because it's only when you write to the last element of your `string` array — that is, when you ask `scanf` to write 13 characters to that last row, when there's only room form 12 — that's the first time you actually write outside the `string` array, and overwrite some other piece of data in your program, with unpredictable, destructive results.

Answer (score 0):

Your one of the arrays you use for reading is redundant. You can use only `string[][]` or only `file_contents_resultset[][]`.

I found that your problem is in the `strcpy()` call. Reading from the buffer is fine, but `strcpy()` seems to copy a blank character in the memory location of `file_contents_resultset[0][0]`.

So to fix it by keeping as much of the program intact i did:

```c
// ...
// stores only one row at a time
char string[12];
// ...

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    fscanf(pFile, "%12s", &string);
    strcpy(file_contents_resultset[i], string);
}

// ...
}
```

If you want to be more concise and save memory, you can remove `string` altogether and just write:

```c
// ...
// char string[12];
char file_contents_resultset[20][12];
// ...

// brackets in loops and other blocks can be omitted
// if the block is just 1 line long. 
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   fscanf(pFile, "%12s", &file_contents_resultset[20][12]);
// ...
```

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks.  that solution does seem to work.   My program is actually about 500 lines long so I was trying to simplify it down to the heart of the issue so I understand why some things may seem redundant.   Do you have any idea why this ONLY fails if I have >19 rows of imput?   I've consistently reproduced this.

Comment: Unfortunately I too was unable to think of why that happens.